# Html5 Video & Source tag

Tags: html, video

I'm working with the html5 video tag, `<video>`, and noticed something that was coming up as an error in Brackets Validator.

What's concerning my is the `<source>` tag inside in the video tag. How I've normally written this is

```
<source src="somecoolvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
```

But this is coming up as an error, stating that it needs a closing `</source>`

```
<source src="somecoolvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
```

Now both ways do work in a browser and I haven't read anything about using the `</source>` so I'm a bit confused on what is the correct practice. Anyone know whats the correct practice?

Comment: @Zsigoveny What does that have to do with the video tag?

Comment: What browser are u using?

Comment: _“in Brackets Validator”_ – who’s that? Seriously, stand-alone elements don’t _need_ closing tags in HTML5 (although you _can_ write them, if you want to be XML compatible, see http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-polyglot/html-polyglot.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's interesting, because [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/embedded-content-0.html#the-source-element) doesn't say it's required and none of its examples have the closing tag.

Sounds like whatever "Brackets Validator" is doesn't correctly validate HTML5.  What does the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org) say about it?  If I enter this into the W3C validator, it validates just fine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>test</title></head>
<body>
    <video>
        <source src="somecoolvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</body>
</html>
```

Additionally, if I do add a closing `</source>` tag, W3C gives an error:

```
Line 6, Column 66: Stray end tag source.
    <source src="somecoolvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
```

So it would appear not only that not having a closing tag in this case is valid, but additionally that actually having one is *explicitly* invalid.

Comment: I just did some research into the validator that Brackets uses and it uses HTMLHint (http://htmlhint.com/), so its not using the W3C validator. Safe to say, I'm removing this extension. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 7):

No, the `<source>` element must not have a close tag and must not close itself, the validator you're using is incorrect.

Here is the [W3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/source.html):

> The source element is a void element. **A source element must have a
>   start tag but must not have an end tag.**

A void element is an element whose content model never allows it to have contents under any circumstances (void elements can have attributes however).

A proper example:

```
<video controls>
 <source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4"
         type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1, mp4a"'>
 <source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.ogv"
         type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
 <p>Your user agent does not support the HTML5 Video element.</p>
</video>
```

Answer (score -1):

Both your examples are correct. You can use closing tags whenever you want like this

```
<video src="Video/Movie.mp4" width="320" height="240" controls poster="Img/My.jpg">
    <a href="Video/Movie.mp4">Download movie</a>
</video>
```